# What's the difference between git add * and git add ., if any?

Tags: git, git-add

[git animals](http://git-animals.tumblr.com/post/24638261758/git-init-git-add-git-commit-a-m-initial) had this series of commands:

```
git init
git add *
git commit -a -m ‘initial commit and release!’
```

What does `git add *` do compared to `git add .` (which I normally do) are they the same?

Comment: * usually means "Match Everything" and . means "this current directory," which by default is done recursively.

Comment: @TylerH4: But if the expansion of `*` includes directories they will be added recursively by git in any case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`git add *` will add all the paths that are the result of the *shell* expansion of `*` whereas `git add .` will tell git to add the current directory.

`git add *` won't add paths that begin with a `.` as the shell expansion of `*` considers these to be "hidden" paths.

`git add *` will also fail if any expanded path is currently being ignored by git because git considers it an error if you explicitly specify an ignored path without passing the `-f` (force) flag to show that you really want to add an ignored path.

If you get git to expand the glob (`git add '*'`) it will add "hidden" files and skip over ignored files. It would work the same as `git add .` in this case.

Comment: Does *shell* here mean the command line application or the OS?

Answer (score 2):

By default passing a directory to `git add` will recursively add its sub-directories and files.

The wildcard `*` will be expanded by your shell as files' names below current directory.

In Unix `.` refers only to the current directory, so these two commands are usually equivalent. Though `*` is processed by the shell and `.` is processed by git, they usually do the same thing.

However, note that `*` in shell expansion usually doesn't include hidden files (files that has a `.` prefix, e.g. `.formatter.yml`). Also, the shell expansion doesn't respect git ignored files in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Since `*` is processed by the shell, it does not take into consideration `.gitignore`, whereas `.` does.

Comment: Good point @wisbucky. If you have a python project and if you do ` git add * `, the "pycache" will be added despite explicitly specifying in .gitignore