# Why won't "git add *" add files that "git status" says are unstaged?

Tags: git

When I type

```
git add *
```

it acts as if there were no files added, yet when I do

```
git status
```

it shows files that are unstaged. I can stage them by manually typing the name, as shown in the picture, but that takes quite a while in same cases.

My question is why, in this instance, can I not just type "git add *" to add the unstaged files, and how should I resolve this? Thank you in advance.

This image shows the behavior I am encountering https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2dxc.png

Comment: type command "git log --graph --decorate" and show image

Comment: Could you show what's in your `.gitignore`?

Comment: Does `git add -u` or `git add -A` work?

Comment: This is the output from that command. http://i.imgur.com/qJz22Vw.png

Comment: My .gitignore literally only has "/Bootstrap" in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add all files, don't use '*' (which is interpreted by the shell)

```
git add .
```

`git add -u` would add updated files. `git add -A .` combines the two.
See "[What's the difference between `git add .` and `git add -u`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190440/6309)"
Also "[Difference between “git add -A” and “git add .”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/6309)":

The `.` indicates the command operates in the current subdirectory instead of the entire working tree.

If you want to known if a file is ignored: `git check-ignore -v -- yourFile`.

---

As explained in "[What's the difference between `git add *` and `git add .`, if any?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971285/6309)":

> `git add *` will add all the paths that are the result of the **shell expansion of `*`** whereas `git add .` will tell git to add the current directory.
>
> `git add *` won't add paths that begin with a `.` as the shell expansion of `*` considers these to be "hidden" paths.

[torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) explains [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949979/why-wont-git-add-add-files-that-git-status-says-are-unstaged/24950133#comment38777711_24950133) why '`*`' fails in this particular scenario:

> in this particular case, `git add *` becomes

```
git add Bootstrap afile bfile ... index.php main.js ... zfile
```

> or some such, and **`git add *` stops with a fatal error** because you told it:
>
> - "don't add `Bootstrap` via `.gitignore`", and
> - "do add Bootstrap via explicit path"
>
> It does not know which to obey, so it does nothing at all.

Comment: Alternativly use `git add -u` to add all updated files and `git add -A` to add all files, even untracked ones and deletions. +1 for `check-ignore`.

Comment: Doing it with a period works. Can you explain more exactly what the period indicates? For example, I though the "*" added all unstaged changes. Thank you.

Comment: Could someone explain the difference between the ., -u, and -a. Thanks! That would be really helpful for me.

Comment: @Connorelsea `.` indicates the current dir.

Comment: @Connorelsea I have edited the answer with links explaining the difference

Comment: The edits you made to your answer are very helpful @VonC. I will make this the accepted answer. Also, what does `git add *` do then?

Comment: @Connorelsea I have edited the answer with why '*' isn't a good idea.

Comment: And, in this particular case, `git add *` becomes `git add Bootstrap afile bfile ... index.php main.js ... zfile` or some such, and `git add` stops with a fatal error because you told it "don't add `Bootstrap` via `.gitignore`, and do add `Bootstrap` via explicit path" and it does not know which command to obey, so it does nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks @torek , that is a very good explanation of what is actually happening, and helped me to understand the situation at a deeper level.

Comment: @Connorelsea I have edited the answer to include torek's comment

Answer (score 0):

Check if you really want to ignore the directory `Bootstrap/` which you say is in your `.gitignore`. Also, as @VonC mentioned in his answer, the correct way to add the current directory to the staging area is `git add .`