# Deleting a file in a git hub directory

Tags: git, github

I save my work on GitHub. Normally, I use the following commands:

```
git add *  # To save all files
git commit -m "a commit"
git push
```

It works perfectly except for one case: Let's say my repository has two files, `file1.c` and `file2.c`.

I use above commands, everything is saved. Then, I delete `file2.c`, only `file1.c` is left.

I run above commands again, and there is no error, but when I clone the repository, both files will be there.

How do I remove these files from my repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `git add *` ([which is expanded by the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971285/6309)) try:

```
rm file2
rm file3
...
git add .
git commit -m "record modified files, remove files"
git push
```

That should take into adccount addition *and deletion* of files, [since Git 2.0 (where `git add .` is like `git add -A`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/6309)

That would record your 20 deleted files, and allow you to push that.

`git add .` would detect automatically the files modified, added or removed.
As opposed to `git add *`, which is managed by the shell, expanding the '`*`' to the files seen by the shell (ie, by definition, *not* the deleted files!)

Comment: And do you know a way to not use the rm file2 ...
If I don't know the name of all deleted files or don't want to track them ?

Comment: @f42 you don't have to know the name of the deleted file: `git add .` will detect them for you :)

Comment: @f42 I have edited my answer to explain why the other answers were missing the point. Your problem comes from using '*', as I detail in my edit.

Comment: The best way to do it, I didn't see your answer first.
I tried and it works.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete a file with git, use the following command:

```
git rm file2.c
```

This will delete the file both on the file system and in the repository.
You can then commit and push the changes as usual:

```
git commit -m "Removed file2.c"
git push
```

If you have deleted a lot of files without `git rm`, you can remove all files from the repository, then add them again:

```
git rm --cached *
git add *
```

The `--cached` deletes files only from the repository, they are kept on the file system so that you can add them back with `git add`.

Comment: Thank you for the command, but how to to if I have 20 files to delete ?
Have you a way to just save the work and if a file is missing automatically delete it from the repository ?

Answer (score 0):

```
git rm file1.c
git add *
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

Comment: Please explain the difference between your lines and the ones the OP is using

Comment: Its the same. Posted at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use git rm to delete file or folder like you use rm in linux ~

for example, run

- git rm path/file2.c
- git status

you will see file2.c is deleted in you repository

then commit it to your remote repository

- git commit -m "del: delete the file file2.c"